# C++: looping over a string - iterator?

Tags: c++, string, loops, c++11, iterator

Let us assume I have different functions accessing a single String `str` (getting a single character of it) and I want to loop through this string with every access...how could I achieve this?

For example:

```
string str = "abc";
function1(); // returns "a"
function2(); // returns "b"
function3(); // returns "c"
function4(); // returns "a" again
function2(); // returns "b" again
...
```

So basically I have different functions accessing this string `str` and I need some kind of iterator which gets back to the first character of `str` if the end of `str` is reached.

Comment: So make such iterator. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use an iterator instead of indexing, you could use a cyclic_iterator, something like this:

```
#ifndef CYCLIC_ITERATOR_H_INC_
#define CYCLIC_ITERATOR_H_INC_
#include <iterator>

template <class FwdIt>
class cyclic_iterator_t : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, typename FwdIt::value_type> {
    FwdIt begin;
    FwdIt end;
    FwdIt current;
public:
    cyclic_iterator_t(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) : begin(begin), end(end), current(begin) {}

    cyclic_iterator_t operator++() { 
        if (++current == end) 
            current = begin; 
        return *this; 
    }
    typename FwdIt::value_type operator *() const { return *current; }
};

template <class Container>
cyclic_iterator_t<typename Container::iterator> cyclic_iterator(Container &c) { 
    return cyclic_iterator_t<typename Container::iterator>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

#endif
```

This is quite minimal as iterators go--for example, it currently only supports pre-increment, not post-increment (and it's a forward iterator, so about all you can do with the iterator is increment it and dereference it).

Nonetheless, for the job you envision, it seems to be adequate.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just index out of the `string` using the `%` modulus operator. This will get you the wraparound behavior you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abc";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << str[i % str.size()] << " ";
    }
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/2jtd)

```
a b c a b c a b c a
```

Comment: yeah...but the problem is there is no single for-loop looping through the string but different functions doing some stuff and accessing the string. Would you suggest a "global" index so that every function called does something like `str[globalindex % str.size()]`?

Comment: It would really depend on the structure of your program. I'm not sure how `function1`, `function2`, etc are related. Are they class methods? Can you explain what your overall goal is with this?

Comment: It is part of a crypto-analysis console tool...the functions are not related (neither in a class nor in a semantic way).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many times you need this to work, but here you are(You can edit it to fit with your needs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "abc";

    bool bAgain = true;

    int Max = str.length() + 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << "\n";

        if(bAgain)
        {
            if(i == Max - 1)
            {
                i = -1;
                bAgain = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

[Output](http://cpp.sh/6qa6)

```
 a 
 b 
 c 
 a 
 b 
 c
```